# Securing Resource Connection Data/Strings For Use by Microservices in Azure

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-keyvault

Various microservices will need access to various Azure resources, each of which has various connection string/authentication key requirements.

I'm thinking that Azure Key Vault is the best way to store the connection information for each resource,  with the microservices authenticating themselves in order to gain access to the connection information they need.

Is this a best-practice approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so. You can secure access to your key vaults by allowing only authorized applications and users. As you need access to various **Azure resources**, I think it is very convenient to use Azure key vault.

Besides, **Azure Key Vault uses Hardware Security Modules (HSMs) by Thales**. Special about HSMs is that they do not give you keys. You create or import a key into an HSM. Later on you give data to the HSM and the HSM is executing cryptographic operations on that data. E.g. encrypting, decrypting, hashing ect. By the way, those hardware devices are really expensive. With Azure Key Vault you are able to use this protection for a small price. That's one benefit using Azure Key Vault.

**Reference:**

[Best practices to use Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/key-vault/key-vault-best-practices)